# How to copy textarea to clipboard for Firefox (see the http://j.mp copy button)?

Tags: firefox, copy, clipboard

I wonder how the http://j.mp can use the auto copy function. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Flash is the only solution i think (at least, when I looked for the same solution a few years ago). Here is a [complete example](http://ajaxian.com/archives/auto-copy-to-clipboard) and some interesting comments. You should find what you need.

Comment: As a complement : ZeroClipboard seems to be a recent and serious project and has a complete documentation, and some working examples.
http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: what is the full URL for: <embed src="/zeroclipboard.js"> ?

Comment: Everything's here http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions It is a library so you have to import it, then declare a "client" in your javascript function, and save text using client.setText(YourSelection). I can't make it magic.

Answer (score 0):

They use Flash to copy to clipboard.

```
<embed 
    width="46" 
    height="26" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    src="/static/CopyClipboardButton.swf?v=3.0" 
    flashvars="copyTextContainerId=short_url&amp;fontSize=14&amp;fontFace=Helvetica&amp;fontColor=#555555&amp;imageUrl=http://j.mp/static/images/index_copy_button_bento_dark.jpg&amp;copyText=" 
    wmode="transparent"/>
```

Comment: please give me complete source code. For an example, i want to copy this text: bla bla bla. Can you give me the full code please?